# MP3 radio Stream buffer underrun detection

Tags: stream, buffer, mp3, internet-radio

any pointers to detect through a script on linux that an mp3 radio stream is breaking up, i am having issues with my radio station when the internet connection slows down and causes the stream on the client side to stop, buffer and then play.

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to detect when the *source end* of the stream is not able to output at a fast enough rate?  Or when the *player client* cannot receive data at a fast enough rate?

Comment: Yes when the source stream is not able to output as fast enough rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

## Method 1:  Assume constant bitrate

If you know that you will have a constant bitrate, you can measure that bitrate over time on the server and determine when it slows below a threshold.  Note that this isn't the most accurate method, and won't always work.  Not all streams use a constant bitrate.  But, this method is as easy as counting bytes received over the wire.

## Method 2:  Playback on server

You can run a headless player on the server (via `cvlc` or similar) and track when it has buffer underruns.  This will work at any bitrate and will give you a decent idea of what's happening on the clients.  This sort of player setup also enables utility functions like silence detection.  The downside is that it takes a little bit of CPU to decode, and a bit more effort to automate.

## Method 3 (preferred): Log output buffer on source

Your source encoder will have a buffer on its output, data waiting to be sent to the server.  When this buffer grows over a particular threshold, log it.  This means that output over the network stalled for whatever reason.  This method gets the appropriate data right from the source, and ensures you don't have to worry about clock synchronization issues that can occur over time in your monitoring of audio streams.  (44.1 kHz to your encoder might be 44.101 kHz to a player.)  This method might require modifying your source client.